# Centralizar tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou com o seguinte código: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3x5jo

Como faço para centralizar as "tabs", ou seja:

```
 <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Deixar os titulos das tabs alinhados no meio?

Comment: `<ul class="nav panel-tabs text-center">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou assim:

```
<style>
.panel-tabs{text-align: center;}
</style>
```